# screws, bolts or nails for ground level deck framing

Tags: deck, screws, joists, bolts, nails

Following up [framing for ground level deck](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/124137/framing-for-ground-level-deck)

I'm putting `2x8` for framing of the ground-level deck, it is a floating deck, i.e. not attached to the house. So, `2x8` joists will be sitting around perimeter of the framing.

What's best to use, nails/screws/bolts, for attaching together 2x8 with 2x8 ? There are many different products in hardware store, for instance galvanized nails/screws, lag screws (or bolts?), so I'm not sure what to choose.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally I would have just used 20d galvanized box nails, 4 per joist end.. Since you're nailing into end grain you need a substantial fastener. Hot-dipped galvanized nails have a rougher texture that grabs fairly well.

However, since your deck is floating I'd maybe want to use screws. This will keep any motion that occurs from working things loose. 3-1/2" Torx drive  screws that are coated for exterior use would be good.

Comment: if the boards aren't old, don't you _want_ them to have some slight range of motion to for allow expansion and contraction of the wood? I thought that overly-tight connectors lead to warping, but maybe that's only for furniture and not for decking...

Comment: isherwood, thanks for comment. Are galvanized steel angles required, for instance http://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-12-Gauge-Angle-A33/100374962 or http://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-ZMAX-18-Gauge-Galvanized-Steel-Angle-A23Z/100375310 ?

Comment: @dandavis, no. Framing doesn't normally get that type of treatment (except for wall and roof sheathing).

Comment: @Mark, if anything you could use standard joist hangers to carry the load. No corner bracing is warranted, in my opinion.